Tkinter GUI window freezes, how can I work around the issue?
This is an issue within a larger program that charges and discharges supercapacitors. The CELL_DISCHARGE function is a function that, as the name suggests, discharges the cells of the supercapacitors attached. In the function, the GUI window freezes after several calls of
 CELL_DISCHARGE_frame.update_idletasks()

This is the entire function:
def CELL_DISCHARGE():

    SCPI_instrument_frame.grid_forget()
    CELL_DISCHARGE_frame.grid()

    #cell discharge
    global Chroma_address
    global DAQ_address
    rm = pyvisa.ResourceManager()
    myChroma = rm.open_resource(Chroma_address)
    my34970A = rm.open_resource(DAQ_address)
    ttk.Label(CELL_DISCHARGE_frame, text="Cell discharge for 3 minutes").grid(row=0, column=0, pady=10)
    voltage_label = ttk.Label(CELL_DISCHARGE_frame, text="Voltage")
    voltage_label.grid(row=2, column=0, pady=10)
    progress = ttk.Progressbar(CELL_DISCHARGE_frame, orient="horizontal", length=180, mode="determinate")
    progress.grid(row=1, column=0, pady=10)
    progress["maximum"] = 180

    print("cell discharge for 3 minutes") #3min is for test 10 min for live
    DAQ_status = my34970A.query("*IDN?")
    print("DAQ Serial:" + DAQ_status)
    myChroma.write('CHAN 1') #discharge
    myChroma.write('MODE CCL')
    myChroma.write('CURR:STAT:L1 ' + str(Discharge_curr)) #CC, static, ch 1 (discharge), 1A
    myChroma.write('LOAD ON')
    
    my34970A.write("ROUT:OPEN (@202,204,206,208,210,212,214,216,218)") #unaffected / set to discharge
    #debug*******************************************************************
    my34970A.write("ROUT:OPEN (@302,304,306,308,310,312,314,316,318)") #unaffected / set to discharge
    #debug*******************************************************************
    my34970A.write("ROUT:CLOS (@201,203,205,207,209,211,213,215,217,219)") #affected / set for in circuit
    #debug*******************************************************************
    my34970A.write("ROUT:CLOS (@301,303,305,307,309,311,313,315,317,319)") #affected / set for in circuit
    #debug*******************************************************************
    for countdown in range(180,0,-1):
        progress["value"] = 180 - countdown
        CELL_DISCHARGE_frame.update_idletasks()

        print(str(countdown) + ": Seconds Remaining - initial discharge")
        max_range = Num_samples + 101
        for t in range(101,max_range,1):
            code = 200 + (t)
            print(code)
            #serialcomm.write(str(code).encode())
            my34970A.write('MEAS:VOLTAGE:DC? AUTO, DEF, (@' + str(t) + ')')
            voltage = float(my34970A.read())
            print("Voltage for Channel " + str(t) + " = " + str(voltage) + " VDC")
            voltage_label.config(text="Voltage:" + str(voltage))
            CELL_DISCHARGE_frame.update_idletasks()
        if msvcrt.kbhit():
            ASCII_in = ord(msvcrt.getche())
            if ASCII_in == 120:
                break
        time.sleep(1)

I tried using multithreading to solve the issue as I have seen this suggestion already, however the program does not behave as expected. With threading added, the code looks as follows:
import threading

def CELL_DISCHARGE():
    SCPI_instrument_frame.grid_forget()
    CELL_DISCHARGE_frame.grid()

    # Cell discharge
    global Chroma_address
    global DAQ_address
    rm = pyvisa.ResourceManager()
    myChroma = rm.open_resource(Chroma_address)
    my34970A = rm.open_resource(DAQ_address)

    ttk.Label(CELL_DISCHARGE_frame, text="Cell discharge for 3 minutes").grid(row=0, column=0, pady=10)

    # Create a progress bar
    progress = ttk.Progressbar(CELL_DISCHARGE_frame, orient="HORIZONTAL", length=180, mode="determinate")
    progress.grid(row=1, column=0, pady=10)
    progress["maximum"] = 180  # 180 seconds = 3 minutes

    # Create the label separately from the grid layout call
    voltage_label = ttk.Label(CELL_DISCHARGE_frame, text="Voltage: -- VDC")
    voltage_label.grid(row=2, column=0, pady=10)

    def discharge_process():
        print("cell discharge for 3 minutes")
        DAQ_status = my34970A.query("*IDN?")
        print("DAQ Serial:" + DAQ_status)

        myChroma.write('CHAN 1')  # discharge
        myChroma.write('MODE CCL')
        myChroma.write('CURR:STAT:L1 ' + str(Discharge_curr))  # CC, static, ch 1 (discharge), 1A
        myChroma.write('LOAD ON')

        my34970A.write("ROUT:OPEN (@202,204,206,208,210,212,214,216,218)")  # unaffected / set to discharge
        my34970A.write("ROUT:OPEN (@302,304,306,308,310,312,314,316,318)")  # unaffected / set to discharge
        my34970A.write("ROUT:CLOS (@201,203,205,207,209,211,213,215,217,219)")  # affected / set for in circuit
        my34970A.write("ROUT:CLOS (@301,303,305,307,309,311,313,315,317,319)")  # affected / set for in circuit

        # Loop for 180 seconds (3 minutes) with progress updates
        for countdown in range(180, 0, -1):
            print(f"{countdown}: Seconds Remaining - initial discharge")

            # Update the progress bar
            progress["value"] = 180 - countdown
            CELL_DISCHARGE_frame.update_idletasks()  # Force update the window

            max_range = Num_samples + 101
            for t in range(101, max_range, 1):
                code = 200 + t
                print(code)

                # Measure voltage
                my34970A.write('MEAS:VOLTAGE:DC? AUTO, DEF, (@' + str(t) + ')')
                voltage = float(my34970A.read())
                print(f"Voltage for Channel {t} = {voltage:.2f} VDC")

                # Update the voltage label in the GUI
                voltage_label.config(text=f"Voltage: {voltage:.2f} VDC")
                CELL_DISCHARGE_frame.update_idletasks()  # Force update the window

            if msvcrt.kbhit():  # Check for keyboard hit
                ASCII_in = ord(msvcrt.getche())
                if ASCII_in == 120:  # If 'x' is pressed, break the loop
                    break

            time.sleep(1)  # Wait for 1 second before next iteration

    # Run the discharge process in a separate thread
    discharge_thread = threading.Thread(target=discharge_process)
    discharge_thread.start()

With this change added, I expected the program to run the discharge in a separate thread from the GUI, but this runs the discharge_process in a separate thread and continues with the next steps of the program. How can I better implement the multithreading or possibly use an event handler instead? This solution will need to also work for several other function calls throughout the duration of the charging and discharging process.

time.sleep is what causes the GUI to freeze.  Replacing the  for countdown in range(180,0,-1): loop with a function which calls itself using tk.after should work.  Without your libraries and hardware I can't test it.  There will be many ways to use after to achieve what you want.  Searching stackoverflow for [tkinter] after and sleep will find lots of examples.
def do_countdown( countdown ):
    progress["value"] = 180 - countdown
    CELL_DISCHARGE_frame.update_idletasks()

    print(str(countdown) + ": Seconds Remaining - initial discharge")
    max_range = Num_samples + 101
    for t in range(101,max_range,1):
        code = 200 + (t)
        print(code)
        #serialcomm.write(str(code).encode())
        my34970A.write('MEAS:VOLTAGE:DC? AUTO, DEF, (@' + str(t) + ')')
        voltage = float(my34970A.read())
        print("Voltage for Channel " + str(t) + " = " + str(voltage) + " VDC")
        voltage_label.config(text="Voltage:" + str(voltage))
        CELL_DISCHARGE_frame.update_idletasks()
    if msvcrt.kbhit():
        ASCII_in = ord(msvcrt.getche())
        if ASCII_in == 120:
            break
    if countdown >= 0:
        CELL_DISCHARGE_frame.after( 1000, do_countdown, countdown-1 )

do_countdown( 180 )

